# Simplify $\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}}{n} - \frac{n - \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}}{1 - \theta} = 0$ to show that $\theta = \bar{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify $\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}}{n} - \frac{n - \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}}{1 - \theta} = 0$ to show that $\theta = \bar{x}$

$\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}}{n} = \frac{n - \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}}{1 - \theta}$

$\Rightarrow \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i} - \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i} \cdot \theta = n^{2} - n\cdot \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}$

$\Rightarrow  - \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i} \cdot \theta = n^{2} - n\cdot \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i} - \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}$

$\Rightarrow \theta = -\frac{n^2}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}} + n + 1$

And then I am kind of lost, how can I manipulate the expression on the right to make it $= \bar{x}$?

Comment: What is $\overline{x}$ here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is probably to note at the beginning that the sum is $n\overline x$, so the equation becomes
$$\overline x-\frac{n-n\overline x}{1-\theta}=0\ .$$
I don't get $\theta=\overline x$ for the solution though, are you sure you have posted the right equation?